# How to mute the microphone c#

Tags: c#, keypress, microphone, mute

I wanted to know, what would the coding be if I wanted to toggle mute/unmute of my microphone. I am making a program that can run in the background and pickup a keypress event and toggle mute/unmute of the mic. Any help with any of that coding would be very helpful. I am pretty new to C#, and this is just a really simple program I wanted to make. That is all it does, is it will listen for keypress of the spacebar, even when the program is in the background, then when the spacebar is pressed it will mute/unmute the mic.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: P.S. It could also mute a single device, because I am "Listening" to the microphone, or playing it through my computer's speakers, so Windows Vista, and 7 will show the individual programs using the Volume Mixer, so if there is a way to programatically mute/unmute a single program, that method will work too.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows Vista and newer, you can no longer use the Media Control Interface, Microsoft has a new [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370802%28VS.85%29.aspx) that you must access to interface with audio hardware in these newer operating systems.

Ray Molenkamp wrote a nice managed wrapper for interfacing with the Core Audio API here:
[Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx?msg=2489276)

Since I needed to be able to mute the microphone from XP, Vista and Windows 7 I wrote a little [Windows Microphone Mute Library](http://computercabal.blogspot.com/2010/11/mute-microphone-from-c-on-windows.html) which uses Ray's library on the newer operating systems and parts of [Gustavo Franco's MixerNative library](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931) for Windows XP and older.

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: You can use that https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/4.0.0-alpha5

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source of a whole application which has muting the microphone, selecting it as a recording device, etc.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/

Answer (score 0):

you can use MCI ([Media Control Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757151(VS.85).aspx)) to access mics and change their volume system wise. Check the code below it should be setting volume to 0 for all system microphones. Code is in c; check [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MIXERLINE.html) for details on how to translate this code to c#

```
#include "mmsystem.h"
...
void MuteAllMics()
{
    HMIXER hmx; 
    mixerOpen(&hmx, 0, 0, 0, 0); 

    // Get the line info for the wave in destination line 
    MIXERLINE mxl; 
    mxl.cbStruct = sizeof(mxl); 
    mxl.dwComponentType = MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_DST_WAVEIN; 
    mixerGetLineInfo((HMIXEROBJ)hmx, &mxl, MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_COMPONENTTYPE); 

    // find the microphone source line connected to this wave in destination 
    DWORD cConnections = mxl.cConnections; 
    for (DWORD j=0; j<cConnections; j++)
    { 
        mxl.dwSource = j; 
        mixerGetLineInfo((HMIXEROBJ)hmx, &mxl, MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_SOURCE); 

        if (MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_SRC_MICROPHONE == mxl.dwComponentType) 
        {
            // Find a volume control, if any, of the microphone line 
            LPMIXERCONTROL pmxctrl = (LPMIXERCONTROL)malloc(sizeof MIXERCONTROL); 
            MIXERLINECONTROLS mxlctrl = 
            {
                sizeof mxlctrl, 
                mxl.dwLineID, 
                MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_VOLUME, 
                1, 
                sizeof MIXERCONTROL, 
                pmxctrl
            }; 
            if (!mixerGetLineControls((HMIXEROBJ) hmx, &mxlctrl, MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE))
            { 
                DWORD cChannels = mxl.cChannels; 
                if (MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLF_UNIFORM & pmxctrl->fdwControl) 
                    cChannels = 1; 

                LPMIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED pUnsigned = (LPMIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED) 
                malloc(cChannels * sizeof MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED); 
                MIXERCONTROLDETAILS mxcd = 
                {
                    sizeof(mxcd), 
                    pmxctrl->dwControlID, 
                    cChannels, 
                    (HWND)0, 
                    sizeof MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED,
                    (LPVOID) pUnsigned
                }; 
                mixerGetControlDetails((HMIXEROBJ)hmx, &mxcd, MIXER_SETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE); 

                // Set the volume to the middle (for both channels as needed) 
                //pUnsigned[0].dwValue = pUnsigned[cChannels - 1].dwValue = (pmxctrl->Bounds.dwMinimum+pmxctrl->Bounds.dwMaximum)/2; 
                // Mute 
                pUnsigned[0].dwValue = pUnsigned[cChannels - 1].dwValue = 0;
                mixerSetControlDetails((HMIXEROBJ)hmx, &mxcd, MIXER_SETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE); 

                free(pmxctrl); 
                free(pUnsigned); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                free(pmxctrl); 
            }
        }
    } 
    mixerClose(hmx); 
}
```

[here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.mmedia/2005-07/msg00075.html) you can find more code on this topic

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

I have several microphones in win7 and class WindowsMicrophoneMuteLibrary.CoreAudioMicMute is incorrect in this case.

so I change the code and works great because now his cup Whistle all microphones and not just in the last recognized by win7.

I am attaching the new class to put in place.

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1145354/dotnet/langages/csharp/couper-micro-sous-win7/

Comment: how does this help mute a microphone?